# TensorFlow concatenate/stack N tensors interleaving last dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assume we have 4 tensors, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` which all share the same dimensions of `(batch_size, T, C)`, we want to create a new tensor `X` which has the shape `(batch_size, T*4, C)` where the `T*4` is interleaved looping between all of the tensors.

For example, if `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` were tensors of all ones, twos, threes and fours respectively we'd expect `X` to be something like

```py
[[[1,1,1...],
  [2,2,2...],
  [3,3,3...],
  [4,4,4...],
  [1,1,1...],
  [2,2,2...],
  .
  .
  .
]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your example array actually has the shape `(batch_size, T, C*4)` rather than `(batch_size, T*4, C)`. Anyway, you can get what you need with tf.concat, tf.reshape, and tf.transpose. A simpler example in 2d is as follows:

```
A = tf.ones([2,3])
B = tf.ones([2,3]) * 2
AB = tf.concat([A,B], axis=1)
AB = tf.reshape(AB, [-1, 3])
AB.eval() #array([[1., 1., 1.],
   # [2., 2., 2.],
   # [1., 1., 1.],
   # [2., 2., 2.]], dtype=float32)
```

You concatenate A and B to get a matrix of shape (2,6). Then you reshape it which interleaves the rows. To do this in 3d, the dimension which is multiplied by 4 needs to be the last one. So you may need to use tf.transpose, interleave using concat and reshape, then transpose again to reorder the dimensions.

Comment: Your comment about the actual shape is wrong - but this code works anyhow with 4 tensors of size `(batch_size, T, C)` using this call `X = tf.reshape(tf.concat([a,b,c,d], axis=2), [batch_size, -1, C])` I get the needed result, in the shape of `(batch_size, T*4, C)` - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think another option is to use [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile).

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

A = tf.ones((2, 1, 4))
B = tf.ones((2, 1, 4)) * 2
C = tf.ones((2, 1, 4)) * 3
ABC = tf.concat([A, B, C], axis=1)

print(ABC)
#tf.Tensor(
#[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3.]]
#
# [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3.]]], shape=(2, 3, 4), dtype=float32)

X = tf.tile(ABC, multiples=[1, 3, 1])

print(X)
#tf.Tensor(
#[[[1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3.]]
#
# [[1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [2. 2. 2. 2.]
#  [3. 3. 3. 3.]]], shape=(2, 9, 4), dtype=float32)
```